# Slick + Play Framework Logging

Tags: scala, logging, slick

I'm trying make simple app with Play Framework 2.4 and Slick 3.0 . My first tries work fine with H2 database, but i have got gramar exceptions when use Oracle 11g express database or MySql database. To solve this mystery, I tried turn on slick logging system, but i have problem with it.

I work with http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/gettingstarted.html tutorial. I remove
 `"org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"` 
from sbt dependencies and add

`logger.scala.slick=DEBUG`

`logger.scala.slick.session=DEBUG`

into application.conf and

`<logger name="scala.slick" level="DEBUG" />`

`<logger name="scala.slick.session" level="DEBUG" />`

into logback.xml but neither of this won't work.

What i do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

I had use wrong logger name. This is correct one.

```
    <logger name="slick.jdbc" level="DEBUG"/>
```